# WiFi issues with ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo Ideapad 510

Tags: wireless-networking, lenovo-laptop, wifi-configuration, ubuntu-16.04

I installed the system using Rufus bootable USB and made the WiFi work fine.

I was able to boot the system from the HDD afterwards and to connect to my WiFi.

Now, after some weeks WiFi is behaving really strange:
 - sometimes it does not show the available connections at all
 - sometimes it shows some available WiFi connections, but not the one I want to connect to!? 
 - sometimes it even shows my WiFi connection, but it keeps trying to connect and cannot
 - it does not update the list of available connections at all, I have to reboot it to try again

In summary, my WiFi is not working now.

Anybody had similar experience?

**UPDATE:**
Based on an answer, I did sudo lshw -class network, and it returned the following:

```
*-generic
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Illegal Vendor ID
   vendor: Illegal Vendor ID
   physical id: 0
....
```

This is a brand new laptop, so it's probably a software problem.

How can I do something about this?

**UPDATE 2:** 
If I boot the computer using the USB, then will sudo lshw -class network return more meaningfull data and show my RTL8821AE druver under network.

Answer (score 0):

After installing 16.04, several issues were discovered.  I followed these steps to correct my problem.  You can find more details [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762198/16-04-lts-wifi-connection-issues)

1. Get details of your PCI wireless card by running ***sudo lshw -class
   network***
2. Get your card model info according to the product line.
   For instance, as you can see in the question description it says
   ***product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter*** so the model of my card is RTL8723BE **OR** ***product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller*** so the model of my card is RTL8101/2/6E
3. Give the permission ***sudo chmod 755 /etc/pm/config.d/***
4. Open or create config and ***add SUSPEND_MODULES="rtl8723be"***(replace rtl8723be with your own model number)
   Then run
   ***echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf***.  Finaly restart your system.

Now your system should be able to reconnect automatically after sleep, and wifi connection never got lost once for me after doing this.

Comment: I tried and it did not worked. UPDATE in the question explains it.